# Usage of 'there'

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context, semantics, clauses, dependent-clause

'There will be no produce if we are not there.'
Can the clause 'If we are not there' be used to mean 'If we don't exist/survive' in the sentence?
Would it be semantically correct?
Would it be in line with English idiom and currency?

Comment: It's looks locative rather than existential.

Comment: In other words, the "not there" is more often used to imply not being present (either physically or via some sort of communication), vs implying non-existence.

Comment: If you think it may be ambiguous, consider the wider context (paragraph, section, chapter, etc). Context is often useful for disambiguation.

Comment: No, it doesn't mean that. If you don't exist or survive you will not be present (there). Unless your corpse counts. But the reverse is not necessarily true. Just because you aren't there doesn't mean that you don't exist or survive.

Comment: You could use it that way. For example, A says, "What will happen to all our fruits and vegetables if humans and animals become extinct?" B answers, "There will be no produce if we are not there." In this context, the sentence is idiomatic and grammatically correct. _There_ might take on a slight ironic tinge here, because it might seem to be making light of the horror or violence of extinction. But it works. As many of the people who post on this site never tire of saying -- and they are right -- context is everything.

Comment: @IsabelArcher Thank you.